# Можно ли изменить ответ переда отправкой пользователю?

Tags: php

Есть ли у PHP функция, которая вернёт то, что сформировано на данный момент для отправки пользователю, что можно было бы доработать и отправить пользователю?

Comment: Вы про var_dump ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ob_start();
echo "<p>Hello, $world!</p>";
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Дальше делайте с этой строкой что хотите.